# How to read a SOAP request body that being sent from the consumer

Tags: spring-boot, soap, soap-client

Hi I am creating a newly spring boots service that will provide a service to get the request from the consumer then send that request to third party service.

However, I am struggling to read that SOAP request from consumer. It is null.

My SOAP request looks like as below that coming from the consumer.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ver="http://www.test.com/bs/testing">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ver:Request>
         <ver:message>
            <ver:m_control>
               <ver:control_timestamp>2023-10-03</ver:control_timestamp>               
            </ver:m_control>
            <ver:person>
               <ver:forename>Mike</ver:forename>               
               <ver:middlename>Rat</ver:middlename>
               <ver:surname>Dobby</ver:surname>
               <ver:sex>M</ver:sex>           
               
            </ver:person>
           
         </ver:message>
      </ver:Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My Spring boot controller looks like as below

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class SoapController {


    private final SoapService soapService;
    
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate/getResponse", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Response> readSOAPRequest(           
            @RequestBody Request request) throws Exception {
           log.info("Request++: " + request.getMessage().getPerson().getForename());

        
        Response response = soapService.callService(request);
        return response  ; // have to update later ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve by converting @RestController to @Endpoint.

Comment: What did this accomplish exactly?

Comment: I will update shortly